# SF CLI: What time zone is the Time in CreatedDate for the package version create list command?

Tags: salesforcedx, sf-cli

```
sf package version create list --created-last-days 0 --target-dev-hub MyDevHub --status Error --json
```

The returned JSON includes, among other things, a time stamp that looks like this:

`"CreatedDate": "2023-11-14 05:41",`

What is the time zone for the timestamp of **5:41**?

Comment: Since Salesforce stores the datetime values in UTC I would have to imagine this value is also UTC. Can you check to see if that checks out?

Comment: @ZackWalton - I checked and noticed that the value matches the local value of the machine. On my work computer I get CreatedDate coming back matching my time zone. However if I run the same command in a remote server machine the created time matches that of the time zone of the machine. Possibly SF transforms the timestamp to match that of the time zone of the machine that runs the command.